# Why my first div background is not red

Tags: html, css, background

```css
  body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  
  .green {
    background-color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%);
  }
  
  .cyan {
    background-color:  hsl(180, 100%, 50%);
  }
  
  .blue {
    background-color:  hsl(240, 100%, 50%);
  }
  
  div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }

  div.main {background-color:red;}
```

```html
   <div>
  <div class="main">
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="cyan"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

My div background should be red but it is not doing it. Did I made an error or something because I have literally no idea why does background-color: red; doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 2):

Tip: Try to use the Inspector to find out, if it actually works or not

```
background-color: red;
```

is working just fine, if you disable background-color for the others you can see that it's red, but the other divs and their background obstruct the red one.

also you defined each div to be 100px * 100px this includes your main div, hence it's only as big as the others even if it contains all the others.

Comment: Could you explain me what does "Inspector" mean?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Most have a built-in developer mode nowadays. If you're using Chrome, right-click your box and 'inspect', then you'll see the page elements and a 'style' tab where you can edit and enable/disable styles on the elements.

Comment: Every major browser (including Edge and Safari) has developer tools, that mostly include a DOM inspector, the hotkey on windows is for most browser: F12
Or rightclick and select "inspect" as @Rup has pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

It's working but you are facing an **overflow issue** because you set a fixed `width`/`height` for **all** the divs. So the main div is equal in height to its first child. Change its height to auto to avoid this and you will see the red color.

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.green {
  background-color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%);
}

.cyan {
  background-color: hsl(180, 100%, 50%);
}

.blue {
  background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 50%);
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

div.main {
  background-color: red;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="cyan"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also remove the extra div and put back the `.main` element a block one with an auto width:

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.green {
  background-color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%);
}

.cyan {
  background-color: hsl(180, 100%, 50%);
}

.blue {
  background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 50%);
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

div.main {
  background-color: red;
  height: auto;
  width:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="cyan"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

it takes a height and a width

```
  body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  .green {
    background-color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%);
  }

  .cyan {
    background-color:   hsl(180, 100%, 50%);
  }

  .blue {
    background-color:   hsl(240, 100%, 50%);
  }

  div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }

.main {
  background-color:red;
  width:auto;
  height:auto
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give height to the `main` class also so that working area of the div class is defined. while using `height:auto;` it auto fixed the height of the class. And you can use height in either `px` or `%` also. Also if you want to show the div class in same row then use either `display:block;` or `display:flex;`

```css
 body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  
  .green {
    background-color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%);
  }
  
  .cyan {
    background-color:  hsl(180, 100%, 50%);
  }
  
  .blue {
    background-color:  hsl(240, 100%, 50%);
  }
  
  div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }

  div.main {
    background-color:red;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    }
```

```html
 <div>
  <div class="main">
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="cyan"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```